# IEventProcessor not reading from Event Hub

Tags: c#, azure-eventhub

I am currently working through implementing an Event Hub reader using EventProcessorHost and a simple IEventProcessor implementation.  I have confirmed that telemetry data is being written into the Event Hub using Paolo Salvatori's excellent [Service Bus Explorer](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/service-bus-explorer-f2abca5a).  I have successfully configured the EventProcessorHost to use a storage account for leases and checkpoints.  I can see the Event Hub data files in the storage account.  The problem that I am seeing at this point is that the IEventProcessor implementation does not appear to be reading anything from the Event Hub.

I am not receiving any exceptions.  The test console app is connecting to the storage account without issue.  I have noticed that the logging statement I added to the constructor is never being called, so it looks like the receiver is never actually being created.  I feel like I am missing something simple.  Can anyone help me determine what I have missed?  Thank you!

**IEventProcessor** Implementation:

```
namespace Receiver
{
    internal class SimpleEventProcessor : IEventProcessor
    {
        private Stopwatch _checkPointStopwatch;

        public SimpleEventProcessor()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SimpleEventProcessor created");
        }

        #region Implementation of IEventProcessor

        public Task OpenAsync(PartitionContext context)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SimpleEventProcessor initialized.  Partition: '{0}', Offset: '{1}",
                context.Lease.PartitionId, context.Lease.Offset);
            _checkPointStopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            _checkPointStopwatch.Start();
            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }

        public async Task ProcessEventsAsync(PartitionContext context, IEnumerable<EventData> messages)
        {
            foreach (var data in messages.Select(eventData => Encoding.UTF8.GetString(eventData.GetBytes())))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Message received.  Partition: '{0}', Data: '{1}'", context.Lease.PartitionId,
                    data);
            }

            if (_checkPointStopwatch.Elapsed > TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30))
            {
                await context.CheckpointAsync();
                _checkPointStopwatch.Restart();
            }
        }

        public async Task CloseAsync(PartitionContext context, CloseReason reason)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Processor shutting down.  Partition '{0}', Reason: {1}", context.Lease.PartitionId,
                reason);

            if (reason == CloseReason.Shutdown)
            {
                await context.CheckpointAsync();
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Test Console Code:

```
namespace EventHubTestConsole
{
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AsyncPump.Run((Func<Task>) MainAsync);
    }

    private static async Task MainAsync()
    {
        const string eventHubConnectionString =
            "Endpoint=<EH endpoint>;SharedAccessKeyName=<key name>;SharedAccessKey=<key>";
        const string eventHubName = "<event hub name>";
        const string storageAccountName = "<storage account name>";
        const string storageAccountKey = "<valid storage key>";
        var storageConnectionString = string.Format("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={0};AccountKey={1}",
            storageAccountName, storageAccountKey);
        Console.WriteLine("Connecting to storage account with ConnectionString: {0}", storageConnectionString);

        var eventProcessorHostName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        var eventProcessorHost = new EventProcessorHost(
            eventProcessorHostName,
            eventHubName,
            EventHubConsumerGroup.DefaultGroupName,
            eventHubConnectionString,
            storageConnectionString);

        var epo = new EventProcessorOptions
        {
            MaxBatchSize = 100,
            PrefetchCount = 1,
            ReceiveTimeOut = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20),
            InitialOffsetProvider = (name) => DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7)
        };

        epo.ExceptionReceived += OnExceptionReceived;

        await eventProcessorHost.RegisterEventProcessorAsync<SimpleEventProcessor>(epo);

        Console.WriteLine("Receiving.  Please enter to stop worker.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void OnExceptionReceived(object sender, ExceptionReceivedEventArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Event Hub exception received: {0}", args.Exception.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm I wonder if it is an issue with Azure at the moment. None of my apps are able to talk to an Azure Event Hub anymore.

Comment: I can still connect via Service Bus Explorer. I have reviwed the relevant source code, and it seems substantially more complex to connect than the simple tutorials suggest. For being I am just going to use direct consumers and revisit the EventProcessHost layer. Thank you for the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is with your value for **EventProcessorOptions.PrefetchCount**.

I changed your code slightly as shown here (removing the **AsyncPump** and shutting down the receivers cleanly). I found that  **RegisterEventProcessorAsync** throws an exception if the **PrefetchCount** is less than 10.

```
namespace EventHubTestConsole
{
  internal class Program
  {
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       const string eventHubConnectionString =
        "Endpoint=<EH endpoint>;SharedAccessKeyName=<key name>;SharedAccessKey=<key>";
       const string eventHubName = "<event hub name>";
       const string storageAccountName = "<storage account name>";
       const string storageAccountKey = "<valid storage key>";
       var storageConnectionString = string.Format("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={0};AccountKey={1}",
        storageAccountName, storageAccountKey);
       Console.WriteLine("Connecting to storage account with ConnectionString: {0}", storageConnectionString);

       var eventProcessorHostName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
       var eventProcessorHost = new EventProcessorHost(
         eventProcessorHostName,
         eventHubName,
         EventHubConsumerGroup.DefaultGroupName,
         eventHubConnectionString,
         storageConnectionString);

       var epo = new EventProcessorOptions
         {
           MaxBatchSize = 100,
           PrefetchCount = 10,
           ReceiveTimeOut = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20),
           InitialOffsetProvider = (name) => DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7)
         };

       epo.ExceptionReceived += OnExceptionReceived;

       eventProcessorHost.RegisterEventProcessorAsync<SimpleEventProcessor>(epo).Wait();

       Console.WriteLine("Receiving.  Please enter to stop worker.");
       Console.ReadLine();
       eventProcessorHost.UnregisterEventProcessorAsync().Wait();
    }


    public static void OnExceptionReceived(object sender,     ExceptionReceivedEventArgs args)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Event Hub exception received: {0}", args.Exception.Message);
    }
  }
}
```